# Override Woocommerce file from includes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is a Woocommerce plugin file in /includes/admin/meta-boxes/view/html-order-item-meta.php that I would like to modify because some meta data of the Yith plugin is not displayed anymore on the order page in backoffice.
I can simply fix the problem by replacing $meta->key with $meta->display_key in the file but my changes will disappear when I update the Woocommerce plugin.

I would like to know if there is a way to make this change cleanly without it being overwritten each time the plugin is updated.
I already tried to put the file in my child theme but it only works for template files...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look though the file. If there are any filters - use them in your custom plugin or theme. Maybe 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta' or 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data' filter can help you.
If not, try finding filters for the Yith plugin to improve compatibility.
Always use filters and actions in your custom plugin or theme to save your changes after updates.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked with 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data' filter !